# setting data via Jquery/Javascript in a ob_get_contents

Tags: php, jquery

i might not be clear with my question title but here is the code..

```
<?php
$filename = 'myfile.htm';
ob_start();
<?PHP 
 <div id='test'>my original value</div>
?>
$htmlcontent = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents("$filename", $htmlcontent);
ob_end_clean();
```

so this code will eventually create a new file and with the text 'my original value

is it possible if i want to alter the div's value through javascript/jquery before it could be transferred to the file?

why am i doing this? because i would eventually be adding a jquery graph library and want to save it to the file..

later using wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf version of that html page..

Answer (score 0):

No; You'll have to display the page along with all of the javascript you want to use.  Then you create a form to gather the contents of the page (after its been manipulated by your graph library) and post it back to PHP, where it can be saved to file.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well you can try one thing. I don't know how the content of myfile.htm looks like, but you can try to load this content with something like DOMDocument, use the loadHTML method, and getElementById.

so:

```
<div id="test1">value</div>
```

could be retrieved with

```
// pseudo
$dom = new DOMDocument::loadHTML('myfile.htm');
$dom->getElemenyById('test1');
$dom->saveHTMLFile('etc ..
```

execute a $.post and 'manipulate' the existing myfile.htm and overwrite it.

cheers